# Suddenly it is harder to pedal

Tags: shifter

This is related to a previous post, but I thought it best to just start with a new post.

My local bike shop installed an 8 speed indexed shifter on a Huffy MTB which has a 6 gear freewheel.

About 2 weeks later, it started being harder to pedal when in several of the lower gears.

I had to stop several times to move the derailleur and chain a little to get home.

Could that possibly be caused by having an 8-speed shifter with a 6 speed freewheel?

(My bike shop is awaiting a Shimano Tourney Tx50 3x6-speed Thumb Shifter Set to replace the 8-speed shifter.)

Comment: How did you end up with such a mismatch?  Was a part replaced and the shop only had an 8 speed unit in stock ?

Comment: @Criggie That is what happened.

Comment: Instead of "Today my bike started acting strangely"  the question would be clearer if you'd said "Bike shop installed wrong shifter temporarily and gears immediately started shifting poorly"   Bike shop would have done better to fit a temporary friction/thumb shifter instead of an indexed one.

Comment: @Criggie I edited my post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you noticed the chain chattering on the sprocket, then yes, it could be caused by using an 8-speed shifter with a 6-speed freewheel. With indexed shifting, all the drivetrain parts are designed to work together, and if you've got a mismatch--as you do here--you can expect the shifter to pull the chain out of alignment with the sprocket.

Comment: Agreed - OP's only option is to find a gear where it all lines up and just stay in that gear without shifting at all, until the new part is available.

Comment: I ended up replacing the 6 speed freewheel with an 8 speed one. I have had no problems and am enjoying the extra 6 speeds.